# Skip GetTagetLuns, LoacteLuns and FillinLunInfo in VSS HW Provider

Tags: volume-shadow-service

I am writing VSS Hardware provider and am able to create snapshot.Accordingly when traced with tracing tools I notice that upto PostCommitSnapshot is all perfect .After PostCommit Snapshot for The Auto Import of Shadow copies GetTagetLuns, LoacteLuns and FillinLunInfo is required but as I am taking snapshot of a volume on some storage so I do not have ample info to provide to GetTargetLuns.

1. If I am continuing with the same LUNinfo provided in the AreLunsSupported it throws BadSourceLun error in GetTargetLuns.
2. If I try to skip this error by commenting out the checking condition in GetTargetLuns then execution continues till LocateLuns and Then asynchronously waits and then OnLunEmpty method is called and then abort snapshots.
3. I tried setting snapshot state value to VSS_SS_POSTCOMMITTED, but this is reserved for system use.

So I want to skip these methods in Vss Hardware Provider?

Any Help would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 2):

It does not calls them when snapshot context is set to: 
VSS_CTX_FILE_SHARE_BACKUP | VSS_VOLSNAP_ATTR_TRANSPORTABLE at requester side.